# DynamoDB Query Time Based on Table Size

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is there any good documentation on how query times change for a DynamoDB table based on equal read capacity and differing row sizes? I've been reading through the documentation and can't find anything, was wondering if anybody has done any studies into this?

My use case is that I'm putting a million rows into a table a week. These records are referenced quite a bit as they're entered but as time goes on the frequency at which I query those rows decreases. Can I leave those records in the table indefinitely with no detrimental effect on query time, or should I rotate them out so the newer data that is requested more frequently returns faster?

Answer (score -1):

Please don't keep the old data indefinitely. It is advised to archive the data for better performance.

**Few points on design and testing:-**

1. Designing the proper hash key, so that the data is distributed
   access the partitions
2. Understand Access Patterns for Time Series Data
3. Test your application at scale to avoid problems with "hot" keys
   when your table becomes larger

> Suppose you design a table to track customer behavior on your site,
>   such as URLs that they click. You might design the table with a
>   composite primary key consisting of Customer ID as the partition key
>   and date/time as the sort key. In this application, customer data
>   grows indefinitely over time; however, the applications might show
>   uneven access pattern across all the items in the table where the
>   latest customer data is more relevant and your application might
>   access the latest items more frequently and as time passes these items
>   are less accessed, eventually the older items are rarely accessed. If
>   this is a known access pattern, you could take it into consideration
>   when designing your table schema. Instead of storing all items in a
>   single table, you could use multiple tables to store these items. For
>   example, you could create tables to store monthly or weekly data. For
>   the table storing data from the latest month or week, where data
>   access rate is high, request higher throughput and for tables storing
>   older data, you could dial down the throughput and save on resources.

[Time Series Data Access Pattern](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.TimeSeriesDataAccessPatterns)

[Guidelines for table partitions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Partitions)